# Not able to import sql file onto PostgreSql in windows

Tags: postgresql

I tried importing a sql file using

psql.exe -U postgres -d development "d:\myprojects\ruby\HelloWorld\db\data.sql".

I get a message 
"extra command line arguement d:\myprojects\ruby\HelloWorld\db\data.sql ignored"

Any help on this ?

Comment: This is a valid question, with actual problem, code (command line) used and the error. The reason is due to missing argument flag. Instead of closing, perhaps edit or move to dba stackexchange?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Either](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)

`psql.exe -U postgres -d development < "d:\myprojects\ruby\HelloWorld\db\data.sql"`

or

`psql.exe -U postgres -d development -f "d:\myprojects\ruby\HelloWorld\db\data.sql"`